# Is there any other way to connect raspi to azure devops pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, raspberry-pi4

I have already use tfs agent in raspi 3 but it is not supported in raspi 4 whereas hosted agent is also not possible in organizational network (via SSH). i was hoping for any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any other way to connect raspi to azure devops pipeline?

To connect raspi to azure devops pipeline, we need to build Raspberry as a self-hosted agent for Azure DevOps.

After that, Raspberry PI configured as a self-hosted agent in Azure DevOps. Then next step you can create a fully automated CI/CD pipeline for your Raspberry PI projects.

You could check [this document](https://internetofthing.io/post/how-to-setup-raspberry-pi-as-an-azure-devops-agent) for some details.

However, if you want use tfs agent in **raspi 4**, I do not believe we could use it at this moment. That because there is an issue about [Raspbian Buster](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/752763/is-it-possible-to-install-the-agent-on-raspbian-de.html), for the time being there is no perfect solution.

Please check [the document](https://blog.mjjames.co.uk/2019/07/running-tfs-build-agent-on-your.html) about that issue for some more details.

Hope this helps.